# Spinner dropdown arrow doesn't display on Nexus 5/5x

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a custom spinner - in testing on a Nexus 7 (Marshmallow) and Moto X 2014 (Lollipop), everything works as it should. However, when I test on a Nexus 5 or 5X (Marshmallow), the dropdown arrow for the spinner isn't being displayed. I've played around with various alignments and padding, but that hasn't seemed to make a difference.

My spinner XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"/>
```

With this custom style applied via code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Edit: See screenshot of relevant part of layout, with layout bounds shown. That's the spinner, which should have a dropdown arrow to the right.

[image: Spinner on Nexus 5]

Edit 2: And screenshot of the same area on a Nexus 7.

[image: Spinner on Nexus 7]

Comment: It's showing fine in my nexus 5. Can you post you screenshot ?

Comment: Will work on getting you a screenshot - don't have a Nexus 5 so am testing via the emulator after a user reported this on their 5X. For what its worth, this is as part of a layout housed within a viewpager.

Comment: I am also testing this in emulator bro not in real device.

Comment: It's may be because of incorrect color combinations too. Can you post your full spinner codes and java codes where you've set the items in it?

Comment: I doubt it's color combination related - see second screenshot from Nexus 7, everything works correctly there.

Comment: So what if you add this attribute in spinner `android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"`?

Comment: That actually seems to work on both devices - work in the sense that the arrow is visible, although it obviously styles things differently from what I want. Any idea why its fixing the displaying of arrow?

Comment: @amn: its matter of styles or your activity type, best way to create Relative layout and place image of dropdown and spinner in it.. if you need code then i will give you.

Comment: Try adding `android:minWidth="200dp"` in spinner. and will it work if you apply styles like I mentioned above ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna you actually helped me find an acceptable workaround - I still can't get the arrow to display consistently, but it's not really integral for me - so I'm just using `android:background="@null"` to hide the arrow entirely.

Comment: That's ok but as I think it is issue of width of the screen in comparison with nexus 7 and 5. And are you saying you solved this ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna not, not solved as such - the arrow still won't show, even if I try setting the minWidth. However, I've found a workaround by creating an alternative UI that I'm happy with, so thanks for your help with that.

Comment: You are really welcome, That means you created `layout-sw600dp` for nexus 7 and others for rest ?

Comment: No, going off your initial suggestion to set the background, I just set `android:background="@null"`, which removed the dropdown arrow entirely on all devices - I'm happy with that from a UI perspective in this case.

Comment: Hehe, That's fine as you found alternatives, I suggest you adding this as answer and accept yourself, Or let me add same as answer, So that others may find it helpful. Your question is usable for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is it's may be because of width issue between `Nexus 7` and `Nexus 5` so that try adding `android:minWidth="200dp"` or `minWidth` attribute as per you needed.

Second alternatives is add `android:background` attribute so that same styles will be applied to all devices.

```
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
```

If you won't have problem in future by not adding drop down arrow in spinner, as alternate you can set it to `@null` and make same look in every devices.

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add `style="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner"` in your Spinner

Comment: Although I've decided to just work around this by hiding the arrow entirely on all devices, I tested this - unfortunately, still doesn't work on the Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and it turned out that the spinner arrow doesn't show unless you have at least 32dp x 32dp available space for it.

I suspect it's the `android:paddingRight="8dp"` on the TextView that is causing the issue